# Python - Ordenar lista strings por ordem de quantidade de letras crescentes

Tags: string, python-3.x, lista

Tendo eu a seguinte lista:

```
lista_nomes =['Manuel', 'Laura', 'Antonio', 'Jasmim', 'Maria', 'Silvia', 'Lu', 'Pancrácio', 'Diogo', 'Ricardo', 'Miguel', 'Andre']
```

E querendo ordena-la por **ordem de quantidade de letras crescentes.**

Ora, não estou a conseguir o resultado pretendido.
O que eu tenho é o seguinte:

```
    lista_nomes =['Manuel', 'Laura', 'Antonio', 'Jasmim', 'Maria', 'Silvia', 'Lu', 'Pancrácio', 'Diogo', 'Ricardo', 'Miguel', 'Andre']
    lista_nomes.sort()

    print (lista_nomes)

*OUTPUT-> ['Andre', 'Antonio', 'Diogo', 'Jasmim', 'Laura', 'Lu', 'Manuel', 'Maria', 'Miguel', 'Pancrácio', 'Ricardo', 'Silvia']*
```

Não é bem isto que eu queria...

Alguem que me possa ajudar por favor?

Obrigado,

Comment: Não é o "length" do nome que queres?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neste momento está a fazer uma ordenação por ordem Alfabética, e pelo que entendo pretende fazer ordenação pelo tamanho da string de cada elemento, portanto:

```
lista_nomes =['Manuel', 'Laura', 'Antonio', 'Jasmim', 'Maria', 'Silvia', 'Lu', 

'Pancracio', 'Diogo', 'Ricardo', 'Miguel', 'Andre']

lista_ordenada = sorted(lista_nomes, key=len)

print(lista_ordenada)
```

No 1º parâmetro do sorted irá definir a lista que pretende ordenar e no segundo uma função que será executada para cada elemento da lista.

[Referência - Sorting Basics](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting)

Comment: Muito obrigado! Era mesmo isso!! Não me lembrava do "key=len"

Comment: De nada, também fiquei a aprender ;)